# How to add custom select dropdown in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Below is my code i want to add a custom select dropdown, suppose select input name is Grades and it is array ; Grades=["A","B","C","D"]. How to show grades dropdown in ckeditor.
Please help me with solution.
I tried this kind of code in ts file: CKEDITOR.plugins.add('mytoolbar', {....})

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.openTemplate();
}

openTemplate(){
const editorSave = this;
    CKEDITOR.replace(this.editor.nativeElement, {
      extraPlugins: 'mytoolbar',
      toolbar: [
        {
          name: 'document',
          items: [
            'Source',
            '-',
            'Save',
            'NewPage',
            'DocProps',
            'Preview',
            'Print',
            '-',
            'Templates',
          ],
        },
        {
          name: 'clipboard',
          items: [
            'Cut',
            'Copy',
            'Paste',
            'PasteText',
            'PasteFromWord',
            '-',
            'Undo',
            'Redo',
          ],
        },
        {
          name: 'editing',
          items: [
            'Find',
            'Replace',
            '-',
            'SelectAll',
            '-',
            'SpellChecker',
            'Scayt',
          ],
        },
        {
          name: 'forms',
          items: [
            'Checkbox',
            'Radio',
            'TextField',
            'Textarea',
            'Select',
            'Button',
            'HiddenField',
          ],
        },
        '/',
        {
          name: 'basicstyles',
          items: [
            'Bold',
            'Italic',
            'Underline',
            'Strike',
            'Subscript',
            'Superscript',
            '-',
            'RemoveFormat',
          ],
        },
        {
          name: 'paragraph',
          items: [
            'NumberedList',
            'BulletedList',
            '-',
            'Outdent',
            'Indent',
            '-',
            'Blockquote',
            'CreateDiv',
            '-',
            'JustifyLeft',
            'JustifyCenter',
            'JustifyRight',
            'JustifyBlock',
            '-',
            'BidiLtr',
            'BidiRtl',
          ],
        },
        { name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'] },
        {
          name: 'insert',
          items: ['Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'PageBreak'],
        },
        '/',
        { name: 'styles', items: ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'] },
        { name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor'] },
        { name: 'tools', items: ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks', '-', 'About'] },
      ],
      on: {
        pluginsLoaded: function () {
          const editor: any = this,
            config = editor.config;
          // Let the party on!
          const command1 = editor.addCommand('save', {
            modes: { wysiwyg: 1, source: 1 },
            exec: function (editor1: any) {
              const fo = editor1.element.$.form;
              editor1.updateElement();
              editorSave.rxsubmit(editor1);
            },
          });
        },
      },
    });
}
```

**HTML template looks like**

```
<div [hidden]="!isView">
  <textarea
    #editor
    [(ngModel)]="ckEditorcontent"
    #myckeditor="ngModel"
    name="myckeditor"
    debounce="500"
  >
          {{ ckEditorcontent }}
      </textarea
  >
</div>
```